# How to merge many columns into 1 with delimiter

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a case, something like this

[image]

I need to get the "Result_Q1" using T-SQL. I tried using `CONCAT` but it makes the performance slow and also the result for ID "a" was "1;;3". Here's my syntax

```
substring(
    case when Q1_1 = 0 THEN '' ELSE ';1;' end +
    case when Q1_2 = 0 THEN '' ELSE ';2;' end +
    case when Q1_3 = 0 THEN '' ELSE ';3;' end,
    2,
    len(case when Q1_1 = 0 THEN '' ELSE ';1;' end +
    case when Q1_2 = 0 THEN '' ELSE ';2;' end +
    case when Q1_3 = 0 THEN '' ELSE ';3;' end - 2)
```

Any suggestion how to achieve the result?

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a minimal reproducible example. Please refer to the following link:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example
Please provide the following:  
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;)

Comment: Thank you for the reminder @YitzhakKhabinsky. Reminder for me for the next case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this table were normalized properly, you would use string_agg(). Is that an option? if not, then try:

```
select id, q1, q2, q3, 
   stuff(
   case q1 when 1 then ';1' else '' end + 
   case q2 when 1 then ';2' else '' end + 
   case q3 when 1 then ';3' else '' end, 
   1, 1, '') as res
from table
```

If you only add ";X" when needed, then you only need to remove the first semicolon after all the concatenation. [Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=fcd6bcc70a3b8ef07ecae9ea68ae13a1) to demonstrate the code.

Comment: Thank you so much. So many reply and it all works great ! Even though @SMor answers it the simplest one for me

Answer (score 1):

thanks to @LoztInSpace for sample data. You can achieve this using CONCAT_WS as given below. You can also refer to [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/ef0fbc/3)

```sql
create table test(q1 int, q2 int, q3 int);
insert into test
 values
  (0,0,0),
  (0,0,1),
  (0,1,0),
  (0,1,1),
  (1,0,0),
  (1,0,1),
  (1,1,0),
  (1,1,1);
;WITH cte_TABLE AS
(
SELECT 
q1,q2,q3,case when q1 = 1 then 1 end as q1c
,case when q2 = 1 then 2 end as q2c
,case when q3 = 1 then 3 end as q3c
FROM test
)
SELECT c.q1,c.q2,c.q3, CONCAT_WS(';',q1c,q2c,q3c) as Result_Q1
from cte_TABLE as c
```

| q1 | q2 | q3 | Result_Q1 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 | 0 |  |
| 0 | 0 | 1 | 3 |
| 0 | 1 | 0 | 2 |
| 0 | 1 | 1 | 2;3 |
| 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| 1 | 0 | 1 | 1;3 |
| 1 | 1 | 0 | 1;2 |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 1;2;3 |

Answer (score 1):

A nested `STRING_AGG` does the job nicely:

```sql
SELECT *,
    Result_Q1 = (
        SELECT STRING_AGG(v.pos, ';')
        FROM (VALUES (t.Q1_1,'1'),(t.Q1_2,'2'),(t.Q1_3,'3')) v(val, pos)
        WHERE v.val <> 0
    )
FROM myTable t
```

Comment: The OP question is looking for positions, not actual values.

Comment: Righto didn't spot that. Fixed now

Comment: Good answer, +1 from my side!

Answer (score 0):

Quick & dirty would be to create a table of values and join to it.  Either inline or permanent.

```
 select t.*,d from  
 MyTable t inner join
 (values
  (0,0,0,''),
  (0,0,1,'3'),
  (0,1,0,'2'),
  (0,1,1,'2;3'),
  (1,0,0,'1'),
  (1,0,1,'1;3'),
  (1,1,0,'1;2'),
  (1,1,1,'1;2;3')
 ) ref(q1,q2,q3,d)
on T.q1_1=q1 and t.q1_2=q2 and t.q1_3=q3
```

Nothing too clever required.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution based on XML and XQuery. Their data model is based on **ordered sequences**. Exactly what we need. So we can easily build a matrix of positions of ones.

The algorithm is relatively simple:

1. Compose XML out of columns of interest (Q1, Q2, etc.).
2. Convert values of 1 into their positions.
3. Revert back to **result** column of VARCHAR() data type.

The solution is very flexible. Any additional column, like Q4, could be added to the `CONCAT_WS(@comma, Q1, Q2, Q3)` function. That's the only change that is needed.

**SQL**

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, Q1 INT, Q2 INT, Q3 INT);
INSERT INTO @tbl (Q1, Q2, Q3) VALUES
(1, 0, 1),
(0, 0, 1),
(1, 1, 0);
-- DDL and sample data population, end

DECLARE @separator CHAR(1) = ';'
    , @comma CHAR(1) = ',';

SELECT *
    , REPLACE(TRY_CAST('<root><r><![CDATA[' + 
        REPLACE(CONCAT_WS(@comma, Q1, Q2, Q3) COLLATE Czech_BIN2, @comma, ']]></r><r><![CDATA[') + ']]></r></root>' AS XML)
    .query('
        for $x in /root/r
        let $pos := count(/root/r[. << $x]) + 1
        return if (data($x) eq 1) then <p>{$pos}</p>
        else ()
    ')
    .query('data(/p)').value('.', 'VARCHAR(20)')
    , SPACE(1), @separator) AS result
FROM @tbl;
```

**Output**

```
+----+----+----+----+--------+
| ID | Q1 | Q2 | Q3 | result |
+----+----+----+----+--------+
|  1 |  1 |  0 |  1 | 1;3    |
|  2 |  0 |  0 |  1 | 3      |
|  3 |  1 |  1 |  0 | 1;2    |
+----+----+----+----+--------+
```